# Notification Bar Icon white square in Android 6.0

Tags: android-notifications, android-notification-bar, android-6.0-marshmallow

Okay so I know that starting in Android 5.0 the way your *supposed* to do things is to have an all white notification icon on a transparent background, otherwise your notification icons will appear as a white block. However if your target sdk was lower than android 5.0, they'd let you get away with the old way just fine.

This all seems to work on Android 6.0 for the lock screen and the notification drawer, **HOWEVER** in the notification bar I get the white square now, even when my target sdk is lower than android 5.0... Is this a bug in Android, or do I just have to start doing the notification icons in the new way now?

Comment: Reported the issue and was told it was working as intended, and will not be changed, so only option is to adopt the new notification icon styles